# How to reduce SQL Server 2008 loads?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a task scheduler use .NET, the aim is to modify the database record.

There is a requirements, these task schedulers must to execute per second.

I think have a large performance overload to my database server.

How to relieve overload? Add database server? How to? Thanks!

Comment: Please post a sample query, along with the query plan it generates.

Comment: I would expect you can execute hundreds of updates per second as long as only the desired row is touched.  Just make sure you have a primary key (or unique index) to locate the row to be modified.

Comment: Your next question will be, "how do I implement service broker?"

Comment: Need specific information. Table size(s) involved? Is your query using many joins? Performance tuned your query? Indexes correct? Executing a query per second isn't the root cause of the load issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became too long for a comment.

Also you need to include timing information for your current implementation, e.g., you can do 1000 updates per minute or suchlike to help understand your current performance.

There are other factors that influence performance dramatically such as keeping the database, the log, and the index files on separate hard drives. How much memory do you have allocated to sql server. Are you running a significant amount of other processing on your server.

Is upgrading from sql 2000 an option. Sql 2000 has serious problems when you leave it running for a long-time. I have a large customers still running sql2k that restart the server processes regularly because it makes a large performance difference -- same application running on sql2008 does not have this problem. At least the have started to upgrade their servers.

Does the .net application run on a separate machine from the server? Is the network connection between the fast, 100 MB Ethernet should probably be the minimum speed. Any other environmental factors that you think might be significant?

Though the environment factors are not programming as such, they can have a large impact on your throughput.